# users in a domain with NO login scripts

Tags: ldap

I'm trying to write an LDAP query for find all users in a domain with NO login scripts.
The following works for users with a login script = db.bat:
(&(objectCategory=user)(ScriptPath=DA.BAT))

However, what i thought will be the obvious logic for a Null ScriptPath field returns no values:
(&(objectCategory=user)(ScriptPath=""))

I'll appreciate any assistance.

Robd

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!scriptPath=*)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
(&(objectcategory=person)(objectclass=user)(!scriptpath=*))
```

or

```
(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(!scriptpath=*))
```